# Migration from Jboss eap 5.1 to jboss eap 6.1 - Clustered JMS topics

Tags: jboss

I am currently in the phase of migrating my Clustered Application from Jboss eap 5.1 to Jboss eap 6.1 (Jboss AS 7.1). The jboss eap 6.1 uses HornetQ as its JMS system as compared to Jboss eap 5.1 which used JBoss MQ as JMS system.  My application has the requirement of using global and local JMS topics(distributed and non-distributed topics). On jboss eap 5.1, there is a configuration file in the messaging folder called 'xxx-destination-service.xml' which provided a boolean  attribute called 'Clustered' defined for each of the JMS topics. This xml file and the attribute is no longer supported in jboss eap 6.1. Can anyone provide me pointers on how this can be done in jboss eap 6.1.

I am Clustering my application in Domain Mode on Jboss eap 6.1 . So please tell what configuration chnages need to be done in my domain.xml or any other xml file.

TIA for your help.

Ajit